# Generalization of straight line motion under constant acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, differentiation, calculus

My question is that, we all know the three equations of straight line motion under constant acceleration,

\begin{align}
x & =x_{\rm o}+v_{\rm o}\,t+\tfrac12 \mathrm a\,t^2
\tag{1d-a}\label{1d-a}\\
v & =v_{\rm o}+\mathrm a\,t
\tag{1d-b}\label{1d-b}\\
v^2 & =v_{\rm o}^2+2\,\mathrm a\left(x-x_{\rm o}\right)
\tag{1d-c}\label{1d-c}
\end{align}

Is my generalization correct?
\begin{align}
\mathbf r & =\mathbf r_{\rm o}+\boldsymbol v_{\rm o}\,t+\tfrac12\mathbf a\,t^2 \quad \text{(no difference with that)}
\tag{3d-a}\label{3d-a}\\
\boldsymbol v & =\boldsymbol v_{\rm o}+\mathbf a\,t
\tag{3d-b}\label{3d-b}\\
\vert\boldsymbol v\vert^2 & =\vert\boldsymbol v_{\rm o}\vert^2+2\,\mathbf a\boldsymbol \cdot\left(\mathbf r-\mathbf r_{\rm o}\right)
\tag{3d-c}\label{3d-c}
\end{align}

Please explain the general principle of generalization of 1-dimension formulas into 3-dimensions.

And I must add I am very sorry that I print this question not using LaTeX, I really know nothing about it, so I printed it like that, hopefully you will be patient about me.

Comment: You can learn LaTex from here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I will do this, after this semester, thanks a lot

Comment: Deep's answer is the first intuitive step one can do for 1d to 3 d. Just write them all and add with the corresponding unit vectors and finally club things together and write it as a vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the above generalisations are correct, what we do in most cases is that we resolute (or break) any given motion along mutually perpendicular axes (namely x, y and z axes) and then apply these formula separately along each of the axes as: $$v_x=v_{0x}+a_{0x}t$$ $$x=v_{0x}t+\frac{1}{2}a_{0x}t^2$$ $$v_x^2=v_{0x}^2+2a_{0x}x$$ along x-axes. Similarly, $$v_y=v_{0y}+a_{0y}t$$ $$y=v_{0y}t+\frac{1}{2}a_{0y}t^2$$ $$v_y^2=v_{0y}^2+2a_{0y}y$$ and $$v_z=v_{0z}+a_{0z}t$$ $$z=v_{0z}t+\frac{1}{2}a_{0z}t^2$$ $$v_z^2=v_{0z}^2+2a_{0z}z$$ along y and z axes respectively. The reason why we do is because motion along mutually perpendicular axes are independent of each other and hence we can apply these formula separately along the axes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Subscripts for the corresponding acceleration components are needed. Pet-peeve: the acceleration components should also have a 0 for being initial values.

Comment: These equations are equivalent to OP's equations so isn't the statement that OP's equations are the correct vector generalizations of 1D motion true?

Comment: @robphy Thanks for correcting the oversight on my part.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion They are true but my style of writing was not appropriate. So I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: For completeness, you might want to include the initial positions, as seen in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As shown in Figure-01

\begin{align}
\mathbf r & =\mathbf r_{\rm o}+\boldsymbol v_{\rm o}\,t+\tfrac12\mathbf a\,t^2
\tag{01a}\label{01a}\\
\boldsymbol v & =\boldsymbol v_{\rm o}+\mathbf a\,t
\tag{01b}\label{01b}\\
\vert\boldsymbol v\vert^2 & =\vert\boldsymbol v_{\rm o}\vert^2+2\mathbf a\boldsymbol \cdot\left(\mathbf r-\mathbf r_{\rm o}\right)
\tag{01c}\label{01c}
\end{align}

Comment: This time, my phone didn't lag while scrolling to the bottom :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am grateful

Comment: @SG8 : Oh ha ha, I use it in my profile as user BioPhysicist  post here [Special Relativity - Reference Frames S and S′ relative velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/552356/special-relativity-reference-frames-s-and-s-relative-velocity/552434#comment1247755_552434).

Comment: @Sohaib Ali Alburihy : Welcome. Note that  Deep Bhowmik's answer is very good and I suggest you to accept it as the best one.

Comment: @Frobenius, I know I saw your profile before but I didn't know that where BioPhysicist stated that :) And, about your answer without words, I found it interesting/useful, so I upvpted whan I saw it. You always bring new perspective of thinking even for the simple/routine problems. This is really good.